# Javascript ajax request not working

Tags: javascript

I have created a js file to fetch data from a txt file and display it on html but it does not seem to work properly.

```
//Event Handling

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
function (event){
console.log("Inside DOMContentLoaded");
document.getElementById('but').addEventListener("click", function (){
console.log("inside first");
$ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest("/Data/name.txt", function(res){
console.log("inside getRequest");
console.log(request.responseText);
});
});
});
console.log("HELLO");
```

And here is the code for sendGetRequest.

```
(function (global){

var ajaxUtils = {};

//Returns an Http Request Object
function getRequest()
{
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
return (new XMLHttpRequest());
}

else {
global.alert("Ajax is not supported");
return (null);
}
}

//Makes an AJAX request to 'requestURL'
ajaxUtils.sendGetRequest = function(requestURL, responseHandler, isJsonResponse) {
var request = getRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
handleResponse(request,responseHandler,isJsonResponse);
}
request.open("GET", requestURL, true);
request.send(null); //For POST only
}

//Only calls user provided 'responseHandler'
//function if response is ready
//and not an error

function handleResponse(request,responseHandler,isJsonResponse)
{
if((request.readyState == 4) && request.status == 200){
if(isJsonResponse == undefined)
isJsonResponse = true;
if(isJsonResponse === true)
responseHandler(JSON.parse(request.responseText));
else {
responseHandler(request.responseText);
}
}
}

global.$ajaxUtils = ajaxUtils;

})(window);
```

Location of js file: /js/ajax-utils.js and /js/script.js and Location of data file: /Data/name.txt

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: Nothing. Just the first three console.log are displayed.

Comment: I made it work. But the line console.log(res.responseText) is displaying undefined even though file is in the directory.